# Good commuication practices via Serial Port (RS232)

Tags: serial-port, serial-communication

I want to know some general communication strategies, which should be followed for a communication via COM (serial) Port.

I can read/write at the port, also can list all the available ports on the machine. I'm using `Qt` C++ with `QSerialDevice`. For testing on a windows machine with no physical serial port, I'm using VPSE (virtual port)

> ### Typical Flow (assumed):
>
> 1. List all the available serial ports of the computer.
> 2. *Find out at which port my device (micro-controller) is connected* - how to do it?
> 3. Device found.
> 4. Start a thread for reading from the port, another thread for writing it.
> 5. Safely close connection

Finding out *at which port the device is connected* sounds challenging to me. How to achieve it? I guess, I will send a HELLO message to each ports, if my device replies a specific per-defined reply message I can be sure my device is connected at that port. Can I?

Also I think, to seperate threads are necessary because at any time I may receive message from the Micro-controller device.

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: We have similar problem. Take a look at my last question "Serial port - how to perform safe search for my device?", maybe i will get answer more quickly.